# Double-Click to open file in Windows opens multiple copies of the same file

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, double-click

So I have recently in the past few months noticed that when I double click on a file in the Windows File Explorer (excel, word, dwg, dxf are the file types I usually deal with), it will open two copies of the file, in two windows.

I notice this because I always get a notification saying that "the file is already open, would you like to open it in read only?"

If I choose "Yes", I get two tabs/windows open, both with the same file; if I choose "No", then only one window or tab opens with the file.

What could be causing this, and how can it be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Folder options has a setting to use single click. I think that is happening is that your double click is being interrupted as two calls to open the file.

File Explorer > Tools > Folder Options > General tab > Click items as follows

Answer (score 0):

Just in case it turns out you don't have the single-click option enabled per @Ack 's answer, you may want to isolate whether the issue is hardware or systemic.  One easy method would be to use [AHK's](https://www.autohotkey.com/) key history utility (note that you'll need to modify your default script to add a mouse hook to capture mouse inputs).  Here's what the utility looks like:

[image: Screenshot]

From there, determine whether or not you're sending any unintended extra inputs; if yes, then move on to test if it's hardware related (e.g., change mouse) or possibly latency related (log into workstation's local admin without networking/domain and try to reproduce).

Answer (score 0):

I would test the behavior of two things:

1. **Right-click -> Open** with files that are opening twice on double-click. Does selecting **Open** launch one or two instances?
2. What is the behavior with **.txt** files --- assuming they still have the default association of **Notepad**. **Notepad** can usually be counted on to exhibit the "gold standard" of default behavior.

Answer (score 0):

## Reasons for Multiple Instance:

Opening multiple instances of a file or folder could be caused by a multitude of things:

1. Most commonly, its a problem with the mouse-click button, either hardware or software settings, where, if it's clicked fast, reduces the speed of the mouse-click.
2. If multiple instances are opening via <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, or right-click *Open*, it's often a problem with software, file conflicts, or hardware.
3. It can also be caused by an issue with drivers, malware, or system file corruption.

---

### Locating the Fault and Solutions:

1. Navigate to the Desktop via: <kbd>WinKey</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>
2. **Don't use the mouse:** 
    Select a file using  or  arrow keys > <kbd>ENTER</kbd> to open 
    OR 
    Right-click file > Use  or  arrow keys > *Open* > <kbd>ENTER</kbd>
3. If opening 2x in comparison to the mouse double-click, connect a known good mouse/keyboard; If it's not, it's an issue with the mouse/keyboard driver:

   1. Open Device Manager via: <kbd>WinKey</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> > `devmgmt.msc` > OK

      1. *Keyboards* > Right-click keyboard with issue > *Uninstall* 
          *Mice and other pointing devices* > Right-click mouse with issue > *Uninstall*
      2. *Action* > *Scan for hardware changes*
      3. Check for devices with error or question marks, delete them and reinstall drivers
      4. Some drivers may need to be uninstalled via: 
         `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Programs and Features`
   2. Reboot after removing *or* reinstalling any devices, then check if issue persists.
4. If issue persists:

   1. Open an Admin terminal: <kbd>WinKey</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> > `cmd` > <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+OK
   2. Check for and fix system file corruption *(must be executed in order listed)*:

      ```powershell
      # Cleanup Component Store:
        DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup

      # Check Component Store for errors and fix if found (internet required)
        DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth
        # If errors are found, reboot before running SFC

      # Check for system file corruption and fix if found:
        SFC /ScanNow
        # Reboot if any errors are found
      ```

      If without internet access, see [Configure a Windows Repair Source](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/configure-a-windows-repair-source) *(i.e. `install.esd`)*

---

### Check for Malware:

1. Use Malwarebytes to scan and clean any malware
2. Use an antivirus to scan and clean any viruses

   - *Use an antivirus boot disk, boot it, then run a scan*
3. Use CCcleaner and Clean Master to remove temporary files.

   - *Do not "clean" the registry*
4. Reboot

---

If the above solutions do not work, please leave a comment for additional troubleshooting.

Comment: Please use correct markdown for monospaced code

Comment: @JW0914 bro thanx for correcting and improving me which markdown  i used wrongly i cant find do tell me the code   and please do help me to tell how to use  codes for creating   KEYS like "windows key" and  "F2 key" "a2 key"  while answering

Comment: For questions/answers/wikis, see the formatting toolbar above the text box.  You can also click the `?` mark icon at the far right of the formatting toolbar for examples on how to use specific markdown.  All the possible markdown options aren't listed, so for keyboard keys, you'd use `<kbd>SomeKey</kbd>`

Comment: Just an FYI, I completely removed the `msconfig` steps for two reasons, the main being they required additional annotation due to the likely possibility of causing more issues than they solve unless the user is informed specifically what to look for and disable, and, less importantly, this step is unlikely to be helpful in solving the issue.

Comment: @JW0914 bro thanx a lot for your editing suggestions and knowledge about markdown tags I was really searching and finding in google but don't know terminology thanx a lot again it will be useful for my  knowledge and for formating answers and questions thanks a lot greatful to you